# Changing arc direction in php Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using Imagick in php to process and overlap images using compositeImage and then curve the top and bottom borders of the image. To achieve this I used `DISTORTION_ARC`:

```
$distortPoints = array( 120 );
$img->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$img->setImageMatte( TRUE );
$img->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_ARC, $distortPoints, FALSE);
```

This is making the image arc shaped but I'm looking to reverse the direction of the arc(https://photos.app.goo.gl/1JAthzLBoVsozQy97).

Update:

I found a script in Fred's ImageMagick Scripts (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderwarp/index.php), this is doing exactly what I'm looking for but I'm unable to use this in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result from using my ImageMagick cylinderize command to put your image onto a mug.

Image:

[image]

Mug:

[image]

```
cylinderize -m vertical -r 73 -l 120 -w 40 -p 5 -n 94 -e 2 -a 0 -v background -b none -f none -o +24+10 stay_home.jpg coffee_mug1.jpg result.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

See my home page for Pointers for use with PHP exec().

NOTE: For use of my script for commercial purpose, you will need to contact me about licensing.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I need little help with sticker size and position, can you please explain me the parameters passed to set the top and left position? for example if i want to place the sticker 20px from top, 15px from left and size 200px X 200px?

Comment: It does not work that way. The size is determined by the length (vertical) and radius (of the mug) along with the wrap argument. So you have to measure the height of the mug in the image as the length and width of the mug as the diameter = 2*radius. Then the wrap determines how much of the image will wrap around the mug. If you want the image width to fill the front half of the mug, then set the wrap to 50 and the width will be the radius.  The position is set using the offsets argument relative to the center of the mug image. So -o +0+0 is the center.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what effect you really want in ImageMagick. But here are two pairs of examples. The first pair uses -distort arc and second pair uses -distort barrel. In each pair, one image curves one way and the other image curves the other way.

The second command answers your question about bowing the arc downward.

[image]

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel White -distort arc 60 rose1.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel White -rotate 180 -distort arc 60 -rotate 180 rose2.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel White -distort barrel "0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0   0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5"  rose3.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel White -distort barrel "0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0   0.0 0.0 -0.5 1.9" rose4.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried barrel earlier also and was unable to figure out how the parameters are working, in arc we can change the degree but here changing the values are distorting the image and I'm unable to find a doc which explains usage of this.

Comment: arc distortion docs are at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc

Comment: Thanks for your replies, Actually I was looking for cylindrical, for which I found your script (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderwarp/index.php), but I'm unable to use it in php. 
I'm unable to convert your Example script to php for execution.

Comment: You can run my script from PHP exec(). But my cylinderize script will not do what you want as specified in your new post.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply, no problem, I'll go with your script as it's closer to what I'm trying to achieve, I checked your parameters but I'm not able to make it work, for example if my image's name is a.png so can you please let me know what exactly should I pass in exec() after uploading the script to server and adding execution permission?

Comment: You need to specify the length and radius of the desired cylinder in your output image. Those are needed arguments. Post an input image and I will try to help. But you need to give me some idea of what it should look like as a result. Also there will be no curvature of the result in the way arc distorts the image. The result will be a cylinder shape. If you really want it curved as in arc, I suggest you use -distort polynomial with a 2nd or 3rd order warp with manually selected control points.

Comment: I've mug images like your sample and i want to put some stickers on this, but they will not be always full size sticker, let's assume I need to put [This image](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/stay-home-lettering-concept_7316551.htm) on a mug. Thank you